# Do I need a full fledge content management system?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

So I have this website that I'm building and they are wanting to be able to change content and pictures on any page throughout the website. I'm not too familiar with content management systems and don't know if I need a full fledged content management system( joomla/drupal ) or I should just create something. Any suggestions? Also, what is some good software for what I'm looking for?

Comment: I need something that the non-techlient could use easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a full fledged CMS would be cheaper and faster than doing it your self.
The only pitfall is-you will have to learn how to skin the chosen CMS.

Comment: I've done skins of Wordpress and Drupal.  For a simple brochure site, Wordpress wins hands down.  My advice - do some practice skins so you know the limits before giving wireframes or designs to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cushy CMS: http://www.cushycms.com

Looks easy to implement and easy for a client to use.

Answer (score 0):

A blogging platform like Wordpress can sometimes be used as a lightweight alternative to a full CMS. You can set it up so that the site's pages are actually individual "posts" in the system. This enables people who don't know HTML to easily update pages within a friendly user interface.

The main task on the back end would be to create a theme that assigns the individual "posts" to a set page structure, which will require significant customization but shouldn't be too difficult.